# Is there an better way to query whether a condition is fulfilled before a row within a time duration?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I wrote a query to count the amount of item with some conditions. But the query looks complex and take a long time to run. Is there a better way to get the same result?

My table looks like this.

```
timestamp      uid     action      item   state
------------------------------------------------
  2010          1      switch      null      on
  2100          1        move         A    null    
  2300          1        move         A    null
  2700          1        move         B    null
  2013          2      switch      null     off
  2213          2        move         C    null
  2513          2        move         A    null
  2200          3      switch      null     off
  2350          3        move         A    null
  2513          3      switch      null      on
  2700          3        move         A    null
```

Basically, I want to get the number of each item with a condition that state is on before and within a period of time.

My query is

```
WITH action_move (
  SELECT timestamp, uid, item
  FROM table
  WHERE action=move AND item IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT item, count(*)
FROM action_move
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT timestamp
  FROM table
  WHERE 
    uid=action_move.uid
    action=switch 
    AND state=on 
    AND (action_move.timestamp - timestamp) < 1000
)
GROUP BY item;
```

My result

```
item    count
-------------
  A        3
  B        1
  C        0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with window functions.  I think the logic is:

```
select item, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             max(timestamp) filter (where state = 'on') over (order by timestamp) as prev_on
      from t
     ) t
where item is not null prev_on >= timestamp - 1000
group by item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Often times when you could use window functions, in modern postgres you should use `LATERAL`.  A `LATERAL` subclause allows you to reference columns from the parent clause.  So try something like:

```
SELECT item, sum(counts.count) AS count 
FROM table t1,
LATERAL (
  SELECT count(*)
  FROM table t2
  WHERE t1.uid = t2.uid
    AND t2.action=switch 
    AND t2.state=on 
    AND (t1.timestamp - t2.timestamp) < 1000
    ) counts
WHERE action=move AND item IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY item;
```

I'm not sure if I've replicated this exactly.  You might not need the GROUP BY in the outer clause if you have a filter for the specific events you want to aggregate.  Basically the lateral will just let you subselect on the table while referencing the row you are subselecting for.